# I want to use the bootstrap template in react , unable to use javascript files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I want to try using bootstrap template in React. I imported all the CSS files in my component page.

[image]

But I am unable to use the JavaScript files. I imported them in `public/index.html` inside the body. To work properly what should I do ?

[image: I tried this for css, css is working fine]
I tried this for CSS. CSS is working fine

[image: I tried adding js here ,but did not work]
I tried adding jS here,but did not work

Comment: Install Bootstrap using npm, then import it into your app's entry point using `import`. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43722322/how-to-insert-bootstrap-js-to-react-app

Comment: Ok will check thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think for ensure working of JS smoothly you need to use the script as mentioned in the docs, for more refrence don't forget to check the docs -> https://react-bootstrap-v4.netlify.app/getting-started/introduction

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>

<script
  src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"
  crossorigin></script>

<script
  src="https://unpkg.com/react-bootstrap@next/dist/react-bootstrap.min.js"
  crossorigin></script>
```